# Count unique users from db

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure in my db (MySQL):

```
id  group_id    item_id     project_id  user_id
```

Users can have multiple entries withing the same project. How do I count unique users withing a particular project (minus project owner id)?

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS cnt
       FROM myTable
       WHERE project_id = $myProject
       AND user_id != 3
       GROUP BY user_id
```

This looks right but I don't believe I'm getting the right results. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select Count(Distinct user_id)
From MyTable
Where project_id = $myProject
    And user_id != 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Add DISTINCT to your COUNT and eliminate the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS cnt
   FROM myTable
   WHERE project_id = $myProject
   AND user_id != 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `GROUP BY` clause for this.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS cnt
FROM myTable
WHERE project_id = $myProject
  AND user_id != 3;
```

If you want to list the member count *for each* group in the same query, you can GROUP BY project_id:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS cnt
FROM myTable
GROUP BY project_id;
```

By grouping on user_id as you do now, every row in the resultset will contain `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try Distinct?

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(user_id) AS cnt FROM myTable WHERE project_id = $myProject AND user_id != 3
```